# How to get array of all data elements by class name using puppeteer Js

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Lets say the page has the following:

```
<article class="card-info" data-id="1">
<article class="card-info" data-id="2">
<article class="card-info" data-id="3">
<article class="card-info" data-id="4">
<article class="card-info" data-id="5">
<article class="card-info" data-id="6">
```

I tried which returned only 1 id not an array:

```
const dataset = await page.$eval("#card-info", (el) => {
       return {
       id: el.getAttribute("data-id")
           
       }
```

How would you get an array of all the data-id elements.. so that the array is populated with 1,2,3,4,5,6